# Configure FxCopCmd Assembly Compare Mode in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, fxcopcmd

Running FxCop using SonarQube results in an assembly resolve issue as I have an assembly binding redirect which is not recognized by FxCop.

Is there a setting in SonarQube to call FxCopCmd with option `/assemblyCompareMode:StrongNameIgnoringVersion` to solve this problem? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of the SonarQube runner plugin for FxCop does not seem to support either this command line parameter or a setting for specifying ad-hoc parameters.  If you don't feel like adding this support yourself, one workaround would be to change your `fxcopcmd.exe.config` file to add an appropriate `AssemblyReferenceResolveMode` setting.  e.g.:

```
<add key="AssemblyReferenceResolveMode" value="StrongNameIgnoringVersion" />
```

Comment: It is not my prefered solution, but it works for the moment. Thank you very much.